# Relocation strings using awk/sed

Tags: awk, sed, relocation

I would like to relocate strings based on the index number.

Index numbers are shown on the first column, the strings are shown on the second column.

```
 1        path_sparc_ifu_dec_104  
 1        path_sparc_ifu_dec_105  
 2        path_sparc_ifu_dec_63  
 2        path_sparc_ifu_dec_92 
 3        path_sparc_ifu_dec_39  
 4        path_sparc_ifu_dec_43  
 4        path_sparc_ifu_dec_71  
 5        path_sparc_ifu_dec_103  
 6        path_sparc_ifu_dec_99  
 7        path_sparc_ifu_dec_55 
 7        path_sparc_ifu_dec_75  
 7        path_sparc_ifu_dec_93
```

If the index number is 1, corresponding strings are placed on the first row. On the same time, the index number is removed.

The desired output is:

```
path_sparc_ifu_dec_104  path_sparc_ifu_dec_105  
path_sparc_ifu_dec_63  path_sparc_ifu_dec_92 
path_sparc_ifu_dec_39  
path_sparc_ifu_dec_43  path_sparc_ifu_dec_71  
path_sparc_ifu_dec_103  
path_sparc_ifu_dec_99  
path_sparc_ifu_dec_55 path_sparc_ifu_dec_75 path_sparc_ifu_dec_93
```

I think awk/sed can read the file column by column and relocate the strings, but I need help!

I would appreciate any help for this problem.

Best,

Jaeyoung

Comment: Try using $1 as an array index and append a space and $2 to it.  In the END rule, print out each element of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '{
    lines[$1] = ( $1 in lines ? lines[$1] FS $2 : $2 )
  } END {
     for (x in lines) print lines[x]
 }' file
path_sparc_ifu_dec_104 path_sparc_ifu_dec_105
path_sparc_ifu_dec_63 path_sparc_ifu_dec_92
path_sparc_ifu_dec_39
path_sparc_ifu_dec_43 path_sparc_ifu_dec_71
path_sparc_ifu_dec_103
path_sparc_ifu_dec_99
path_sparc_ifu_dec_55 path_sparc_ifu_dec_75 path_sparc_ifu_dec_93
```

Answer (score 1):

My version:

```
$ awk '{if(prev==$1){printf(" ")}else{if(NR!=1){printf("\n")}};printf("%s",$2);prev=$1}END{printf("\n")}' file
path_sparc_ifu_dec_104 path_sparc_ifu_dec_105
path_sparc_ifu_dec_63 path_sparc_ifu_dec_92
path_sparc_ifu_dec_39
path_sparc_ifu_dec_43 path_sparc_ifu_dec_71
path_sparc_ifu_dec_103
path_sparc_ifu_dec_99
path_sparc_ifu_dec_55 path_sparc_ifu_dec_75 path_sparc_ifu_dec_93
```

Because index numbers are sorted we just printing value of the second column but without newline. When index number changed, we are printing newline.